# vlookup multiple sheets and report in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with a workbook that have "Scheduled Payments" from many clients, one in each sheet.

The sheets have this structure - Date - Value - Name - Bank - City

What I need to do is, search for a DATE and copy all rows that have that date in another sheet called "Busca", searching across all sheets.

I'm beginner and my sketch of code is this so far:

```
Sub Pesquisa()

Dim data As Variant 'declarando a variável que vai receber a data a ser buscada
Dim linha As String 'declarando a variável que vai receber o dado encontrado

On Error Resume Next

Worksheets("Busca").Range("relatorio").ClearContents

data = B1

End Sub
```

If someone can take a hand, I can upload the file too.

Thanks

Comment: Turn on the macro recorder, and go through your steps.  When you're done, stop the recorder then step in to it to see the resulting code.  You can use `F8` to go line by line, and watch in Excel what the lines do.  That should get you going on your copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of code that will work, with the following assumptions.

1. The `Date > Value > Name > Bank > City` data for each customer sheet is located starting in cell A2 (row 1 is headers)
2. You place your date in in the `Busca` sheet into cell A1, and have the `Date > Value > Name > Bank > City` headers in row 2 of that sheet.

You can modify these assumptions as needed.

```
Sub Pesquisa()

Dim wsB as Worksheet
Set wsB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Busca")

Dim dDate as Date
dDate = wsB.Range("A1") 'assumes your desired date is in cell A1 of Busca sheet

Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> "Busca" Then 'check all sheets except Busca sheet

        ws.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter 1, dDate

        If Not Intersect(ws.UsedRange,ws.UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Is Nothing Then 
            Intersect(ws.UsedRange,ws.UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsB.Range("A" & wsB.Rows.COunt).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If

    End If

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you!

I used your code and it highlights this part and says syntax error 
 "If ws.Name <> "Busca" 'check all sheets except Busca sheet"

Comment: Do you have `ws` dimensioned as a `Worksheet`? and are you sure you typed all the syntax correctly?

Comment: I've ctrl + c and ctrl +v on what you wrote

Comment: Now the code works, but not the way it supposed to do.

For example, no matter what date i write on the A1 cell of sheet Busca, it always returns the same results.

Comment: bear in mind that I gave you a *sketch of code* that will work. You will have to modify the exact methods to get your data moved as needed. There is no possible way for me to know *exactly* what you needed with the information you provided in your question.